# How to display my sqlite query with separator

Tags: php, sqlite, group-concat

I looking for a solution change de output mode of my sqlite query in my php file. This is my current query

```
SELECT 
  strftime('%m-%d', date) day, 
  round(avg(min),1) as moy_min, 
  round(avg(max),1) as moy_max 
FROM historique GROUP BY day;
```

With this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ29S.png)

But I would like to show this values (moy_min and moy_max) with a simple comma between this 2 values to display it in my highchart. I tried with group_concat, but I can't find the good syntax. Do you know how can I do that ?

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group_concat()` is an aggregate function and can't be applied to another aggregate function like `avg()`.
You can do it with simple concatenation:

```
SELECT strftime('%m-%d', date) day, 
  round(avg(min),1) || ',' || round(avg(max),1) as moy 
FROM historique 
GROUP BY day;
```

Comment: Wahoo ! Thanks a lot. I tried with the || but I forgot to remove the alias ;-)